# prolog returns value twice

Tags: prolog

I am just learning prolog and I ran into the problem where I get the same answer twice when asking for niece and nephew. I just cannot wrap my head around it. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Perhaps it is something having two rules for each cousin? But it works fine when asking for brother or sister..

UPDATE: I tried out some things, and after returning to the code I wrote down here, the rule of a niece being only a female doesn't work anymore. and the nephew returns false.

So I have the code:

```
male( ted  ).
male( john ).
male( aron ).
male( nico ).
male( gio  ).

female( liza   ).
female( sophie ).
female( lily   ).
female( elin   ).
female( daisy  ).
    
parent_of( lily   , aron ).
parent_of( john   , aron ).
parent_of( john   , elin ).
parent_of( lily   , elin ).
parent_of( sophie , gio  ).
parent_of( sophie , nico ).
parent_of( daisy  , liza ).
parent_of( ted    , liza ).
    
father_of(X,Y):- male(X),
    parent_of(X,Y).

mother_of(X,Y):- female(X),
    parent_of(X,Y).

sister_of( X , Y ) :- % (X,Y or Y,X) %
  female(X),
  father_of(F,Y),
  father_of(F,X),
  X \= Y.
sister_of( X , Y ) :-
  female(X),
  mother_of(M,Y),
  mother_of(M,X),
  X \= Y.
    
brother_of(X,Y):- %(X,Y or Y,X)%
  male(X),
  father_of(F,Y),
  father_of(F,X),
  X \= Y.
brother_of(X,Y):- male(X),
  mother_of(M,Y),
  mother_of(M,X),
  X \= Y.

niece_of(X,Y):-
  dif(X,Y),
  female(X), 
  parent_of(W,Y),
  parent_of(P,X), 
  brother_of(P,W).
niece_of(X,Y) :-
  dif(X,Y),female(X), 
  parent_of(W,Y),
  parent_of(P,X), 
  sister_of(P,W).

nephew_of(X,Y) :-
  dif(X,Y),
  male(X), 
  parent_of(W,Y),
  parent_of(P,X),
  brother_of(P,W).
nephew_of(X,Y):-
  dif(X,Y),
  male(X), 
  parent_of(W,Y),
  parent_of(D,X),
  sister_of(D,W).
```

The output I get is

```
?- niece_of(X,liza).
X = aron ;
X = aron ;
X = nico ;
X = nico ;
X = gio ;
X = gio ;
false.

?- nephew_of(X,liza).
false.
```

Comment: Where is `father_of/2` and `mother_of/2`?

Comment: @GuyCoder I updated my code

Comment: The query `nephew_of(X,liza).` fails with the program you provide.

Comment: @damianodamiano I have the same problem now..

Comment: 1. Have you tried drawing out the relationships as a graph and walking the code while moving a token on the graph? 2. If you are using SWI-Prolog have you used gtrace? 3. Since cut is a bit advanced for a person new to Prolog, do you know how to add [guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science)). 4. If you are new to Prolog where did you learn of dif/2 and why are you using it? (If you are just coping and pasting parts of other code without understanding each predicate that can drive one insane). 5. Is this for a class assignment? 6. Are you using any textbooks?

Comment: Think about this, would it not make more sense to define sister_of/2 and brother_of/2 using parent_of/2 and have only one clause instead of what the code does using father_of/2 and mother_of/2 using 2 separate clauses?

Comment: @GuyCoder this doesn't really solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all some simplification and extended family tree

```
male(ted).
male(john).
male(aron).
male(nico).
male(gio).
male(ken).
male(vladimir).

female(liza).
female(sophie).
female(lily).
female(elin).
female(daisy).
female(barbie).

parent(lily, aron).
parent(john, aron).
parent(john, elin).
parent(lily, elin).
parent(sophie, gio).
parent(sophie, nico).
parent(vladimir, gio).
parent(vladimir, nico).
parent(daisy, liza).
parent(ted, liza).

% grandfathers
parent(ken, lily).
parent(ken, daisy).
parent(ken, sophie).
parent(barbie, lily).
parent(barbie, daisy).
parent(barbie, sophie).



father(Father, Child) :-
    male(Father),
    parent(Father, Child).

mother(Mother, Child) :-
    female(Mother),
    parent(Mother, Child).

sibling(X, Y) :-
    father(Father, Y),
    father(Father, X),
    X\=Y.

sister(Sister, Sibling) :-
    female(Sister),
    sibling(Sister, Sibling).
    
brother(Brother, Sibling) :-
    male(Brother),
    sibling(Brother, Sibling).

niece(Niece, ParentsSibling) :-
    female(Niece),
    parent(NiecesParent, Niece),
    sibling(NiecesParent, ParentsSibling).

nephew(Nephew, ParentsSibling) :-
    male(Nephew),
    parent(NephewParent, Nephew),
    sibling(NephewParent, ParentsSibling).
```

[image]

I've added `sibling/2` predicate to remove some reused code.

**Why did you have duplications on nephew?**

You did use the parent predicate there when trying to define the sister of the nephew's parent, in that case, you would get each sibling twice (once because of evaluation with mother and once because of evaluating with father). You can verify that with `trace\0`.

**Workaround**

When looking for siblings I'm checking for 2 people with the same father (check `sibling/2` predicate).

If for some reason your relations would be able to have situations that human beings can exist without fathers it won't work. In that case, you would need to modify `sibling/2` predicate and use `parent\2`, produce all values (with `findall` for example) and then return distinct values.

Comment: but now if I for instance write niece(liza, X) I get the aunts and uncles... My goal was to get all the nieces of liza

Comment: That's true, but you can use `niece(X,liza)` and then you'll get all nieces of liza.

Comment: When I write the comment niece(X,liza). in the terminal, it returns `false.` same with nephew

Comment: I made a few changes here and found what I wanted :) but this was very helpful

Answer (score 3):

First of all, according to your database, there is no one who is anyone's niece or nephew. This can be clearly seen when you draw the graph for the relation `parent_of/2`.

[image]

```
female(lily).
female(sophie).
female(daisy).
female(elin).
female(liza).

male(john).
male(ted).
male(aron).
male(gio).
male(nico).

parent_of(lily, aron).
parent_of(lily, elin).
parent_of(john, aron).
parent_of(john, elin).
parent_of(sophie, gio).
parent_of(sophie, nico).
parent_of(daisy, liza).
parent_of(ted, liza).
```

Now, consider a first version of a rule that defines the relation `siblings0/2`:

```
siblings0(Person1, Person2) :-
    dif(Person1, Person2),
    parent_of(Parent, Person1),
    parent_of(Parent, Person2).
```

Using this rule, there are two distinct ways to prove that *Aron* and *Elin* are siblings (first, because they both have the same mother; second, because they both have the same father). However, there is only one way to prove that *Gio* and *Nico* are siblings (since there is no information on who is the father of each one of them).

```
?- siblings0(aron, elin).
true ;  % <== same mother
true ;  % <== same father
false.

?- siblings0(gio, nico).
true.   % <== same mother
```

To **avoid redundancy**, we can use the the ISO built-in predicate [once/1](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=once/1):

```
siblings(Person1, Person2) :-
    dif(Person1, Person2),
    person(Person1),
    person(Person2),
    once( ( parent_of(Parent, Person1),
            parent_of(Parent, Person2) ) ).

person(Person) :-
    (   female(Person)
    ;   male(Person) ).
```

Now, we get only one answer for each query:

```
?- siblings(aron, elin).
true.

?- siblings(gio, nico).
true.
```

Thus, extending your database and using the predicate `siblings/2` to define other relations, everything will work fine!

[image]

```
female(lily).
female(sophie).
female(daisy).
female(elin).
female(liza).
female(pat).   % <== add

male(john).
male(ted).
male(aron).
male(gio).
male(nico).
male(coy).     % <== add

parent_of(lily, aron).
parent_of(lily, elin).
parent_of(john, aron).
parent_of(john, elin).
parent_of(sophie, gio).
parent_of(sophie, nico).
parent_of(daisy, liza).
parent_of(ted, liza).
parent_of(elin, pat ). % <== add
parent_of(elin, coy).  % <== add
parent_of(gio, pat).   % <== add
parent_of(gio, coy).   % <== add

siblings(Person1, Person2) :-
    dif(Person1, Person2),
    once( ( parent_of(Parent, Person1),
            parent_of(Parent, Person2) ) ).

mother_of(Mother, Child):-
    female(Mother),
    parent_of(Mother, Child).

father_of(Father, Child):-
    male(Father),
    parent_of(Father, Child).

sister_of(Sister, Person) :-
    dif(Sister, Person),
    female(Sister),
    siblings(Sister, Person).

brother_of(Brother, Person) :-
    dif(Brother, Person),
    male(Brother),
    siblings(Brother, Person).

niece_of(Niece, Person):-
    female(Niece),
    parent_of(Parent, Niece),
    siblings(Parent, Person).

nephew_of(Nephew, Person):-
    male(Nephew),
    parent_of(Parent, Nephew),
    siblings(Parent, Person).
```

Examples:

```
?- niece_of(Niece, Person).
Niece = pat,
Person = aron ;
Niece = pat,
Person = nico.

?- nephew_of(Nephew, Person).
Nephew = coy,
Person = aron ;
Nephew = coy,
Person = nico.
```

Comment: Just a warning regarding `once/1`: this does not work properly if parents have more than than two children. E.g. add `parent_of(lily, sarah).` then `siblings(sarah, X).` will only enumerate `X = aron` even though `siblings(sarah, elin).` is also derivable. In other words, the general query does not enumerate all solutions anymore.

Comment: @lambda.xy.x Thanks! I've udpdated my answer to solve the problem!