Sister Predicate Duplicates in Prolog
I need a predicate to find the sister
sister(X, Y) - "X is Y's sister if they have a common parent W, X is a woman and X is not Y".
The problem is that every "child" has two parents. Because of this I get duplicates as a result of the execution, how can I eliminate them?
parent(tetiana, olha).
parent(tetiana, bohdan).
parent(mykola, olha).
parent(mykola, bohdan).

parent(maria, alex).
parent(maria, daria).
parent(mykhailo, alex).
parent(mykhailo, daria).

parent(olha, aristarh).
parent(alex, aristarh).

woman(tetiana).
woman(maria).
woman(olha).
woman(daria).

man(mykola).
man(bohdan).
man(mykhailo).
man(aristarh).
man(alex).

sister(X, Y) :-
    parent(W, X),
    parent(W, Y),
    woman(X),
    X \== Y.
   

?-
sister(X, Y).

X = olha,
Y = bohdan
X = olha,
Y = bohdan
X = daria,
Y = alex
X = daria,
Y = alex

I expect to see it as:
?-
sister(X, Y).

X = olha,
Y = bohdan
X = daria,
Y = alex


You may use setof/3 to remove duplicates:
sister(X, Y) :-
  setof(X-Y, sister_(X,Y), Sisters),
  member(X-Y, Sisters).

sister_(X, Y) :-
    parent(W, X),
    parent(W, Y),
    woman(X),
    X \== Y.

Sample runs:
?- sister(X, Y).
X = daria,
Y = alex ;
X = olha,
Y = bohdan.

?- sister(X, alex).
X = daria.


As noted by @false, you can simplify this and use:
sister(X, Y):-
  setof(t,sister_(X,Y),_).

(or inline it directly). Sample run:
?- sister(X, Y).
X = daria,
Y = alex ;
X = olha,
Y = bohdan.


setof(t,sister_(X,Y),_) is more compact and potentially more efficient.

Use the swi-prolog predicate distinct/1 in the query:
?- distinct( sister(X,Y) ).
X = olha,
Y = bohdan ;
X = daria,
Y = alex ;
false.


To remove the duplication, using the same strategy as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70010881
% S means sister, R means relative
sister(S, R) :-
    % Purest, most useful expression of inequality
    dif(S, R),
    woman(S),
    % Only need this to succeed once
    once((
        parent(P, S),
        parent(P, R)
    )).

Result in swi-prolog:
?- sister(S, R).
S = olha,
R = bohdan ;
S = daria,
R = alex.

As a general point - if there are variable names which convey more meaning than the overused X, Y, etc., then use the meaningful names in preference, to reduce confusion.
